# How to use list comprehension with .extend list method?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example, this snippet:

```
out = []
for foo in foo_list:
    out.extend(get_bar_list(foo)) # get_bar_list return list with some data
return out
```

How to shorten this code using **list comprehension**?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/1639625

Comment: @parsenz No, because this will create a list of list while OP is looking for a flatten list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a generator expression and *consume* it with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable(get_bar_list(foo) for foo in foo_list))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a nested list-comprehension:

```
out = [foo for sub_item in foo_list for foo in get_bar_list(sub_item)]
```

FWIW, I always have a hard time remembering exactly what order things come in for nested list comprehensions and so I usually prefer to use `itertools.chain` (as mentioned in the answer by Moses).  However, if you really love nested list-comprehensions, the order is the same as you would encounter them in a normal loop (with the innermost loop variable available for the first expression in the list comprehension):

```
for sub_item in foo_list:
    for foo in get_bar_list(sub_item):
        out.append(foo)
```